# Model accessor attribute returning related model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

I have a model called `EquipmentProfile` which has a relationship with `EquipmentProfileType` defined like so:

```
public function equipmentType()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(EquipmentProfileType::class, 'equipment_profile_type_id');
}
```

I have an accessor defind on `EquipmentProfile` to enable me to get a specific value from this relationship:

```
public function getCategoryAttribute()
{
    return $this->equipmentType->name;
}
```

I am then including `category` in my `$appends` array so that it is included when I am returning the model as JSON.

This works perfectly, except in my JSON response I am also getting the whole relationship to `EquipmentProfileType` too:

```
//...more fields above
"category": "Brewing",
"equipment_type": {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Brewing",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

I only want `category` to be returned, not the `equipment_type` object too. If I remove `category` from my `$appends` array then `equipment_type` is not included in the response.

How do I get `category` to be returned without `equipment_type`?

**Edit**

My controller calls a method on a repository:

```
public function store(EquipmentProfileRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->except(['api_token']);

    return $this->equipmentProfileRepository->store($data, $request->user());
}
```

Here is the repository code below:

```
public function store(array $data, User $user)
{
    if (!array_key_exists('name', $data) || $data['name'] == '') {
        $data['name'] = 'Equipment Profile';
    }

    $data['user_id'] = $user->id;

    return $this->equipmentProfile->create($data);
}
```

**Note**

Even using `tinker` gives me the same result:

```
Psy Shell v0.9.6 (PHP 7.1.7 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> App\Models\EquipmentProfile::first()->toJson()
=> "{... "category":"Brewing","equipment_type":{"id":10,"name":"Brewing","created_at":null,"updated_at":null}}"
```

Comment: can you add the controller code for this ?

Comment: @Hussein have added this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EquipmentType` model is being included in your JSON output, because the relation is automatically loaded when `getCategoryAttribute()` is called.

To hide it, add the relation name to the `hidden` array on your model. It will then be filtered out when calling `toArray()` and `toJson()`.

```
class EquipmentProfile extends Model
{
    // ...

    protected $hidden = [
        'equipmentType'
    ];

    // ...
}
```

Comment: but it shouldn't be visible in first place cz the code is returning only the name

Comment: If you read the Laravel source code, when a model is serialized (to array or JSON), it includes all attribute values, and all relations. As I said in my answer, because you loaded the relation in order to access the name, it's then included.

Comment: @fubar thanks for the explanation. I thought it had to be something like that. I didn't see anything in the docs and didn't think to check the source code. Adding it to the `hidden` array did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one below:

```
$result = $this->equipmentProfile->create($data);

return response()->json($result, 200, array(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

That should remove any extra variables and objects.